# Blank Screen from Resume - Can still Login

Tags: suspend, hp

This may be a bug - I am testing Ubuntu 13.04 64bit. I have a HP Envy Extreme XT 13.3

When I suspend and resume, I have a blank screen. However I can still enter my password and then wait a few moments and press either of the screen brightness buttons and the screen wakes up.

More information - this PC uses an Intel graphics HD 4000 - Graphics drive is Intel Ivybridge Mobile

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it detects the external monitor that is pluged into the laptops vga port. If I unplug the external monitor it goes to sleep and awake fine. The problem is to stop it from detecting the external monitor.

Kubuntu 13.04

Ok I finally found the answer The system confuses the TV pluged on on vga. It detect the one vga plugin as both TV an vga but it is the same and only plug.

Solution in kde system settings->display click on all displays  except your laptop builtin  display, and disable them then apply.

So only one display should be enabled laptop builtin  display.

cheers